# How to construct a semi-group over a non-numerical set?

Tags: abstract-algebra, semigroups

A semigroup is a set, e.g. $X$, with an associative binary operation, e.g. $\star$. That is for all $x,y,z \in X$, $(x \star y) \star z = x \star (y \star z)$.

I have seen some abstract algebraic books, but there are no examples for a non-numerical set. In other words, let $X = \{ a,b,c,d,e,f \}$. If we represent $\star$ by a table as follow

```
  *   a   b   c   d   e   f  
 ----------------------------
  a | . | . | . | . | . | . |
  b | . | . | . | . | . | . |
  c | . | . | . | . | . | . |
  d | . | . | . | . | . | . |
  e | . | . | . | . | . | . |
  f | . | . | . | . | . | . |
 ----------------------------
```

then what should I put in the table above instead of dots? In other words, what this matrix like representation should look like?

I am new to abstract algebra with a CS background.

Comment: They will be elements of $X$, though there won't be a unique semigroup associated with it; there will be several possible semigroup structures.

Comment: That's right. But my question is how to distribute the elements of $X$ in place of dots such that $star$ is associative?

Comment: There are many ways to do this.

Comment: @AliShakiba I understand, I'm simply stating the fact that there is no single way to distribute those elements.  Moreover, it is in general hard to do except for the most trivial of cases (for example, make $x\star y=a$ for every $x,y\in X$).  Unlike commutativity, where it is easy to make (just assign either upper triangle or lower triangle to determine the rest of the values), the same is not true for associativity.  I recommend looking at Light's associativity test.

Comment: @Tobias Kildetoft That's OK! There are 1160 distinct ones of order 5, 15793 of order 6 and so on according to "P.A. Grillet; Semigroups: An Introduction to the Structure Theory; CRC Press; 1995". But I am generally interested to know the properties, if there are any in general, of this tabular representation so that $(X, \star)$ is a semigroup!

Comment: @Hayden Thanks for the help. I will check it out.

Comment: @Hayden Thanks again, I've checked it. Can you point out some references which explain algorithmic aspects of abstract algebra, semigroups and so on. This way, I feel better in abstract algebra, I think!

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thnaks, I've fixed it. It was a typo.

Comment: You could also see the GAP package [Smallsemi](http://www-groups.mcs.st-andrews.ac.uk/~jamesm/smallsemi.php), it has a library of all of the semigroups up to order 8 (up to isomorphism and anti-isomorphism).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
  *   a   b   c   d   e   f  
 ----------------------------
  a | a | a | a | a | a | a |
  b | a | a | a | a | a | a |
  c | a | a | a | a | a | a |
  d | a | a | a | a | a | a |
  e | a | a | a | a | a | a |
  f | a | a | a | a | a | a |
 ----------------------------
```

and as it says in one of the comments there are 15972 other semigroups with 6 elements (up to isomorphism and anti-isomorphism.

You said:

> But I am generally interested to know the properties, if there are any in general, of this tabular representation so that (X,⋆) is a semigroup!

One answer is the obvious one: the multiplication defined by the table has to be associative.

Another answer might be: there is a result in this [paper](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/2041879?uid=3738032&uid=2&uid=4&sid=21104407007281) stating that almost all semigroups of order $n$ are 3-nilpotent, where almost all means that the proportion of semigroups with this property tends to $1$ as the order tends to infinity.

A semigroup $S$ is *3-nilpotent* if there exists an element $0\in S$ such that $xyz=0$ for all $x,y,z\in S$.

One reason there are so many semigroups with this property is that their multiplication tables are very easy to define:

1. Choose a zero element, let's say $e$ in the example with 6 elements;
2. Choose a set of elements including $e$, say, $\{a,b\}$ in our example, and make every product of these elements equal to the zero element $e$;
3. Define the product of any other two elements to be equal to any of the elements from step 2.

The object with multiplication defined by this construction is always a semigroup, since the product of any 3 elements, written $x(yz)$ or $(xy)z$ is the zero element.

For example,

```
  *   a   b   c   d   e   f  
 ----------------------------
  a | e | e | a | a | e | a |
  b | e | e | a | a | e | a |
  c | a | a | a | a | e | b |
  d | a | a | a | a | e | a |
  e | e | e | e | e | e | e |
  f | a | b | b | a | e | a |
 ----------------------------
```

defines an associative multiplication on the set $\{a,b,c,d,e,f\}$.

The number of 3 nilpotent converges to the number of semigroups (up to isomorphism and anti-isomorphism) quite quickly:

$$
\begin{array}{l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l}
n&1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8\\\hline
\text{number of semigroups}&1& 4& 18& 126& 1160& 15973& 836021& 1843120128\\
 \text{number of 3-nilpotent semigroups}& 0& 0& 1& 8& 84& 2660& 609797& 1831687022\\
\end{array}
$$

So by $n=8$, 99% of the semigroups are 3-nilpotent.